# How to use Docker build step in Github Action to tag branch & platform together

Tags: docker, dockerfile, github-actions

In current my GHA pipeline, I'm building and tagging my docker images the following way:

```yaml
- name: 'Docker meta ${{ matrix.image_name }}'
  id: meta-data
  uses: docker/metadata-action@v4
  with:
    images: |
      ghcr.io/${{github.repository_owner}}/sahl-apps/${{ matrix.image_name }}
    tags: |
      # branch event
      type=ref,event=branch
      # tag event
      type=ref,event=tag
      # pull request event
      type=ref,event=pr
- name: 'Build and push ${{ matrix.image_name }} Docker image'
  uses: docker/build-push-action@v4
  with:
    context: .
    file: './apps/${{ matrix.image_name }}/Dockerfile'
    push: true
    tags: '${{ steps.meta-data.outputs.tags }}'
    labels: >
      org.opencontainers.image.source=https://github.com/${{ github.repository
      }}
    cache-from: type=gha
    cache-to: 'type=gha,mode=max'
```

The thing is, the current tagging configuration was creating multiple images, so since I'm on a free tier on github actions, I wanted to limit as much as possible, so when if my image was tagged with my branch, and the others weren't, I'd delete them:

```yaml
- name: Delete all containers from repository without tags
  uses: Chizkiyahu/delete-untagged-ghcr-action@v3
  with:
    token: '${{ secrets.PACKAGES_PAT }}'
    repository_owner: '${{ github.repository_owner }}'
    repository: '${{ github.repository }}'
    untagged_only: true
    owner_type: org
```

When pulling my image from the ghcr, I'd get the following error:

```bash
> docker pull ghcr.io/repo_owner/sahl-apps/<image-name>:development
development: Pulling from repo_owner/sahl-apps/<image-name>
manifest unknown
```

That's where I realized that the untagged versions of my image were potentially linking to platforms (and manifests), and that deleting them made pulling the image impossible.

My question is the following: how do I limit the number of images, while ensuring that the image tagged with my branch name also contains os/archi info? What can I change in my metadata tagging?

Thanks!